# HorizontalScrollView, View.GONE doesn´t work

Tags: android, view, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView`.

Into this view, I change the `View.GONE` into `View.VISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` into `View.GONE`.

I haven´t got any problem when I pass `View.VISIBLE` to `View.GONE` but, when I change `View.GONE` into `View.VISIBLE` it doesn´t work.

I do it in a specific function `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

and I access to these buttons doing reference to another class where they are declared.

Any idea of what the problem is?
Thank you ;)

Comment: Have you tried instead of `View.GONE` use a `View.INVISIBLE`?

Comment: Yes, and it works. But I need it as View.GONE because it has to be adapted to its center. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Are you declaring your HorizontalScrollView in xml, or are you adding it dynamically to your layout? In the first case it should work, I tested it.

Comment: Yes: `listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);`